# Default method in java 8

Tags: java, oracle, java-8

**Question 2:** What is wrong with the following interface?

```
public interface SomethingIsWrong {
    void aMethod(int aValue) {
        System.out.println("Hi Mom");
    }
}
```

**Answer 2:** It has a method implementation in it. Only default and static methods have implementations(I THINK THIS IS WRONG BECAUSE INTERFACE CANNOT HAVE METHODS WITH BODY BECAUSE BY DEFAULT ITS METHODS ARE ABSTRACT).

**Question 3:** Fix the interface in Question 2.

**Answer 3:**

```
public interface SomethingIsWrong {
    void aMethod(int aValue);
}
```

Alternatively, you can define aMethod as a default method:

```
public interface SomethingIsWrong {
    default void aMethod(int aValue) {
        System.out.println("Hi Mom");
    }
}
```

I found this in docs.oracle.com and I wonder that are these the correct answers provided by ORACLE?
in my opinion.

1.In answer 2,it is written that  Only default and static methods have implementations?

2.In answer 3 alternative ,its given that aMethod can be defined as default Method but 
interface cannot have methood body in it because by default methods in interface are abstract we can only implement its method in its subclass.

Please let me know is ORACLE site right or wrong?

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT AT US.

Comment: If it's worth anything, [this seems to be the related Oracle page in question](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/QandE/interfaces-answers.html).

Comment: @Sheenam you asked nice question in a wrong way

Answer (score 11):

The page you're looking at talks about the soon-to-be-released Java 8, where interfaces can have "default" methods containing an implementation, and can also have static methods.

Before Java 8, interface methods can't, indeed, have an body, and interfaces can't have static methods.

Comment: Oh, fantastic, so we don't need classes any more!  Does this give us multiple inheritance?  The diamond inheritance problem?  Yeeha!

Comment: No diamond problem. See http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-about-the-diamond-problem/. And classes still very much needed. Default methods can't be final. Interfaces still can't have state and constructors.

Comment: That page doesn't satisfy me that there is no diamond problem.  What if (in the example), methods with identical signatures but different implementations were in `B` and `C`?  There's no way to tell which one `D` would inherit.

Comment: *But if both B and C provide default implementations, then they conflict, and D must provide an overriding declaration, possibly using the syntax X.super.m(...) in the body of m to explicitly choose one of the inherited methods.* So the compiler will complain in this case, and force you to choose which implementation you want to use.

Comment: Sorry!  Right you are.

Answer (score 2):

Default method will be introduced in java 8 which is also known as **Defender Methods**.

A important aspect regarding default method which may cause diamond problem in multiple inheritance if the class implements two interfaces and both those interfaces define a default method with the same signature?

```
public interface Foo {
    default void fun(){
       System.out.println("Calling Foo.fun()");
    }
}

public interface Bar {
    default void fun(){
       System.out.println("Calling Bar.fun()");
    }
}


public class FooBar implements Foo, Bar {
}
```

In this case it will produce compile error-

```
java: class FooBar inherits unrelated defaults for fun() from types Foo and Bar
```

In this case class `FooBar` will be forced to override the conflicting method `fun`.So the correct implementation would be

```
public class FooBar implements Foo, Bar {
    public void fun(){...}
}
```

Comment: +1 for "inherits unrelated defaults for fun".  What would a class be if it didn't have any fun?